# How to double loop over a vector of strings in Clojure?

Tags: function, loops, vector, clojure, nested

I have this function that checks the cities in a csv file if they have over a population of 500000.
I saved all the found cities to a vector but now want to loop over the vector twice in order to find the pairs of cities that are close to each other(less than 500km)(i already have a function that checks if two cities are close)
Here is what I have so far:

```clj
(defn closest-city-pairs []
  (with-open [rdr (reader)]
    (vec
      (for [line (drop 1 (line-seq rdr))
            :let [y (string/split line #",")]
            :when (= true (large(y 0)))]
        (let [newVec (conj [] (y 0))]
          (for[x newVec
               y newVec
               :when (= true (close x y))]
            (let [newNewVec (conj [] (x y))]
              (println newNewVec))))))))
```

It doesn't seem to want to print but my logic and all the parentheses seem to make sense and in order? Any help would be great

Comment: `for` is not really what you may know from imperative languages. It's a "list comprehension". You don't have to "stop" for a new `let` in there - just add another `:let` at the end and continue inside the first for (yet i doubt that is what you want - you have right now three nested loops). Move the reading of the data out into a functio, then move the filtering out and finally only do your finding of the close ones last. Having small, pure, properly named functions makes testing and experimenting a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of what you can do, written as a unit test:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(def nums [1 2 3 11 12 13])

(defn close?
  [x y]
  (<= (Math/abs (- x y)) 5))

(dotest
  (let [close-pairs (vec
                      (for [x nums
                            y nums
                            :when (and (not= x y)
                                    (close? x y))]
                        [x y]))]
    (spyx close-pairs))
  )
```

with result:

```
close-pairs => [[1 2] [1 3] [2 1] [2 3] [3 1] [3 2] 
                [11 12] [11 13] [12 11] [12 13] [13 11] [13 12]]
```

so we get a lot of duplicates.  We can eliminate them by simply sending the output into a set, then removing duplicate sets:

```
  (let [close-pairs (vec
                      (distinct
                        (for [x nums
                              y nums
                              :when (and (not= x y)
                                      (close? x y))]
                          #{x y})))]
    (spyx close-pairs))
```

with result:

```
close-pairs => [#{1 2} #{1 3} #{3 2} #{12 11} #{13 11} #{13 12}]
```

You can avoid the set trick (and the work duplication) if you get fancier with the `for` expression, and use indexes for each value.  See the docs [for the `indexed` function](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.core.html#var-indexed)

```
(indexed [:a :b :c]) => ([0 :a] [1 :b] [2 :c])
```

And we can then use the `:when` clause like so:

```
(dotest
  (let [nums-indexed (indexed nums)
        close-pairs  (vec
                       (for [[ix x] nums-indexed
                             [iy y] nums-indexed
                             :when (and (< ix iy)
                                     (close? x y) )]
                         [x y]))]
    (spyx close-pairs)))
```

with result:

```
close-pairs => [[1 2] [1 3] [2 3] [11 12] [11 13] [12 13]]
```

One could reduce the duplicate looping even further with judicious use of the `:while` clause, but that is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

P.S. You'll need to add `[tupelo "0.9.169"]` to `:dependencies` in your `project.clj` to access the `spyx` and `indexed` functions.

Comment: (defn test []
 (def newNewVec [])
    (with-open [rdr (reader)]
        (vec
            (for [line (drop 1 (line-seq rdr))
                :let [y (string/split line #",")]
                :when (= true (large(y 0)))]
                (let [newVec (conj [] (y 0))
       close-pairs 
       (vec
                      (distinct
                        (for [x newVec
                              y newVec
                              :when (and (not= x y)
                                      (close x y))]
                          #{x y})))]
    (spyx close-pairs))))))

Comment: But I'm getting an error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named, compiling:(

Comment: You need to update your question with the new code. It doesn't work in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
(require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as comb])
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv])

(with-open [r (io/reader "cities.csv")]
        (let [cities (->> (csv/read-csv r) (into [] (comp cat (filter large-city?))))]
            (filter close-to-each-other? (comb/combinations cities 2))))
```

Comment: It says  Could not locate clojure/math/combinatorics__init.class or clojure/math/combinatorics.clj on classpath. when I try to implement this

Comment: @RichardDesouza you add a library to the classpath if you use someting like [Leiningen](https://leiningen.org/) or [tools.deps](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli). E.g., add `[org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.1.6"]` to `project.clj` under the `:dependencies` key for Leiningen. See this simple [example](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#projectclj).